# Code in IF and ELSE statement get both executed

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

In my `ngOnInit` hook, I'm loading a list of student dormitories from my data service. If the list is empty (which happens if the list wasn't loaded in an other component before), I have to load the list from the backend.
So what I want my program to do is:

load list from data service -> if (list.length > 0) -> use this list. Else -> load list from backend.

```
ngOnInit(): void { 
  this._update.currentDorms$
  .subscribe(dorms => {
    if (dorms.length > 0) {
      this.dorms = dorms
      console.log("if statement", dorms)
    } else {
      this._data.getDormLocations().subscribe(dorms => {
        this.dorms = dorms;  
        this._update.changeDorms(dorms);
        console.log("else statement", dorms)})
    }
 })
}
```

Both `console.log()` statements get executed when I open the page:

[image: result]

I also tried using `else if (dorms.length == 0)` instead of just `else`, but the result was the same.

I checked, the code above really only appears at the `ngOnInit` hook, so the answer is not that I just copy & pasted it somewhere by mistake and therefore it gets runned twiced... I think maybe it has to do with the Observable in the else statement, does it subscribe to it anyway even if the else statement shouldn't be run?

Comment: They're subscriptions, they can run more than once.

Comment: Oh yes you're right, that was it. The code goes into the else statement first, loads the list from the backend, then I update my data service and therefore fire next on the currentDorms$ Observable. Then the dorms.length is bigger 0 and the if statement gets executed!

Comment: if you want only first emission then use pipe(take(1)).subscribe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observable may emits the data more then once, and so its call back function. If you need get data only once then I recommend to use Promise over Observable. However in your case you have to unsubscribe your subscription

```
ngOnInit(): void { 
  const subscription = this._update.currentDorms$
  .subscribe(dorms => {
    if (dorms.length > 0) {
      this.dorms = dorms
      console.log("if statement", dorms)
    } else {
      this._data.getDormLocations().subscribe(dorms => {
        this.dorms = dorms;  
        this._update.changeDorms(dorms);
        console.log("else statement", dorms)})
    }

    subscription.unsubscribe(); //unsubscribe here
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I don't update the `currentDorms$` Observable in the else part, only the else statement get's executed.
That's because the code goes into the else statement first, loads the list from the backend, then I update the `currentDorms$` Observable in my data service and therefore fire next on the the `currentDorms$` Observable. This runs the code in the subscription again, this time the `dorms.length` is bigger 0 and the if statement gets executed.

Weirdly the console.log form the if statement still get's printed out first.